# Android Cannot serialize: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope when using SOAP

Tags: java, android, soap

```
public void addItem() {
    String url="https://www.aspiresoft.ke/Wt/webtask.asmx";
    String soap_action="http://tempuri.org/AddItem";
    String method_name="AddItem";
    String nameSpace="http://tempuri.org";

    SoapObject soapObject=new SoapObject(nameSpace,method_name);
    soapObject.addProperty("UserName",strName);
    soapObject.addProperty("ItemCode",strItemCode);
    soapObject.addProperty("Description",strDescription);
    soapObject.addProperty("Packaging",strPackage);
    soapObject.addProperty("Unit",strUnits);
    soapObject.addProperty("Photo",strPhoto);

    //configuring soap version
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //specify true when you are calling dotnet WS(.asmx)
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(envelope);

    //setting soap header
    envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
    envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader(nameSpace);


    //transfer request over the network
    HttpTransportSE httpsTranSE=new HttpTransportSE(url);
    try{
        httpsTranSE.call(soap_action,envelope);
        envelope.getResponse();
        SoapObject object=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        String response=object.getProperty(0).toString();
        System.out.println(response);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Header
private Element buildAuthHeader(String nameSpace) {
        Element h = new Element().createElement(nameSpace, "AuthHeader");
        Element username = new Element().createElement(nameSpace, "userName");
        username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "1234");
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
        Element pass = new Element().createElement(nameSpace, "password");
        pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "4321");
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);
        return h;
    }
```

I am using SOAP API in my application. I haven't used this before. When I try to execute I am getting "cannot serialize" error. I have checked this API in Postman, and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code like this

```
public void addItem() {
    String url="https://www.aspiresoft.ke/Wt/webtask.asmx";
    String soap_action="http://tempuri.org/AddItem";
    String method_name="AddItem";
    String nameSpace="http://tempuri.org";

    SoapObject soapObject=new SoapObject(nameSpace,method_name);
    soapObject.addProperty("UserName",strName);
    soapObject.addProperty("ItemCode",strItemCode);
    soapObject.addProperty("Description",strDescription);
    soapObject.addProperty("Packaging",strPackage);
    soapObject.addProperty("Unit",strUnits);
    soapObject.addProperty("Photo",strPhoto);

    //configuring soap version
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //specify true when you are calling dotnet WS(.asmx)
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

    //setting soap header
    envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
    envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader(nameSpace);


    //transfer request over the network
    HttpTransportSE httpsTranSE=new HttpTransportSE(url);
    try{
        httpsTranSE.call(soap_action,envelope);
        envelope.getResponse();
        SoapObject object=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        String response=object.getProperty(0).toString();
        System.out.println(response);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Header
private Element buildAuthHeader(String nameSpace) {
        Element h = new Element().createElement(nameSpace, "AuthHeader");
        Element username = new Element().createElement(nameSpace, "userName");
        username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "1234");
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);
        Element pass = new Element().createElement(nameSpace, "password");
        pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "4321");
        h.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);
        return h;
    }
```

Comment: @Vishali I have made a minor change in your code in this line envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);

Comment: i tried your code after that also i am getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception

Comment: check it carefully what you have set on this line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203317/discussion-between-sandeep-dhiman-and-vishali).